# Using References (many-to-one) in Fluent NHibernate creates a Foreign Key in both ends, the many end and the one-end

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

as the title says, I would like to create a many-to-one relationship using Fluent NHibernate. There are GroupEntries, which belong to a Group. The Group itself can have another Group as its parent.

These are my entities:

```
public class GroupEnty : IGroupEnty
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual IGroup Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group : IGroup
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual IGroup Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And these are the mapping files:

```
public class GroupEntryMap : ClassMap<GroupEntry>
{
    public GroupEntryMap()
    {
        Table(TableNames.GroupEntry);
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        ...
        References<Group>(x => x.Group);
    }
}

public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Table(TableNames.Group);
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        ...
        References<Group>(x => x.Parent);
    }
}
```

With this configuration, Fluent NHibernate creates these tables:

```
GroupEntry
bigint Id     string Name     ...     bigint Group_id

Group
bigint Id     string Name     ...     bigint Parent_id     bigint GroupEntry_id
```

I don't know why it creates the column "GroupEntry_id" in the "Group" table. I am only mapping the other side of the relation. Is there an error in my configuration or is this a bug?
The fact that "GroupEntry_id" is created with a "not null" constraint gives me a lot of trouble, otherwise I would probably not care.

I'd really appreciate any help on this, it has been bugging me for a while and I cannot find any posts with a similar problem.

**Edit:** I do NOT want to create a bidirectional association!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I accidentally assigned the same table name for two different entities... Shame on me :(

Thanks a lot for the input though!

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted, but since the author didn't have his tables posted I wasn't sure if he had the same issue with the unnecessary foreign key. I'm glad you figured it out though, I was stumped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a many-to-one where a Group has many Group Entries I would expect your models to look something like this:

```
    public class GroupEntry : IGroupEntry
    {
       public virtual long Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        ...
       public virtual IGroup Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group : IGroup
    {
       public virtual long Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        ...
       public virtual IList<GroupEntry> GroupEntries { get; set; }
       public virtual IGroup Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Notice that the Group has a list of its GroupEntry objects.  You said:

> I don't know why it creates the column "GroupEntry_id" in the "Group" table. I am only mapping the other side of the relation.

You need to map both sides of the relationship, the many side and the one side.  Your mappings should look something like:

```
    public GroupEntryMap()
    {
        Table(TableNames.GroupEntry);
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        ...
        References<Group>(x => x.Group);  //A GroupEntry belongs to one Group
    }
}

public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Table(TableNames.Group);
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        ...
        References<Group>(x => x.Parent);
        //A Group has-many GroupEntry objects
        HasMany<GroupEntry>(x => x.GroupEntries); 
    }
}
```

Check out the fluent [wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one) for more examples.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I explicitly do not want a bidirectional association. The business logic doesn't need it and it would only create additional overhead when mapping DTOs. I am using bidirectional associations in other components, which work fine, but I am also using unidirectional associations like this one and they also work fine. I just can't figure out why NHibernate creates a foreign key in both entities in this specific case.

Comment: I just found a sample on the NHibernate website which does exactly the same thing I want to realize: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-3-mapping-relations.aspx
The blog-author association reflects my situation, and I can't find any differences.